# Loop Through Visible Worksheets with Moved Charts

Tags: excel, vba

Morning

I need some help and not really sure where to begin.

I have an excel workbook, which populates a sheet of data from a SQL stored procedure. There are then a series of pivots off the data, all easy so far. I then create charts off those pivots and move them to their own sheets.

What I want to achieve is a rolling dashboard of those charts, say every 30 seconds, change sheet. I have tried a few things, grabbed a few ideas off this site, but for some reason, the sheets with the charts on will not loop with the others, so in effect I only see my data page and pivot page. Below is some code that I tried to modify for my purpose.

```
Sub TabShow()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Pause As Double

Pause = 3 'Pause delay
Loops = 3 'How many loops do you want to do

For j = 1 To Loops

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

        Worksheets(i).Select 'Select the next worksheet

        x = Timer
        While Timer - x < Pause 'This does the pausing
        Wend

    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

So if anyone has any code that loops through visible sheets including ones of moved charts, I would be eternally grateful.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Time arithmetics: in VBA, time is stored in Date, being Date binary equal to Double, being each unit one day. So, `Pause = 3` means 3 days!!! Better:

```
Dim Pause As Date
Pause = #0:0:30# 'Time constant
```

I recommend also using `Now` instead of `Timer`.

Program flow: while running a macro, Excel become irresponsive, unless you use `DoEvents`:

```
 While Timer - x < Pause 'This does the pausing
     DoEvents
 Wend
```

That will ensure your workbook will allow user interaction while macro is running.

However, I do not recommend keeping a macro running while working on it. Check `Application.OnTime` for a better approach.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. When I try your code above, I enter the pause = part but when I move to the next line it changes to 12:00:30AM. Sorry if this is me being dumb, VBA isnt my strongest

Comment: That's correct. `#12:00:30AM#` means 30 seconds after midnight, that's the way VBA shows times.